# serialVersionUID added to JSON

Tags: android, json, gson, serialversionuid

I am converting an object to JSON using `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4` library by using code:

```java
String json = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.PROTECTED).create().toJson(object);
```

And in the JSON string "serialVersionUID" is added automatically with `Long` value even if it is not in a model class. I just want to remove `serialVersionUID` from JSON.

Comment: `serialVersionUID` must be `static`.

Comment: but there is no serialVersionUID field in my class.

Comment: Then your class inherits a class that has a non-static `serialVersionUID` field. Can you modify the base class and make that field static as it's supposed to be?

Comment: When I am using new Gson().toJson(object) then it is no adding serialVersionUID in JSON.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was wrong about the Gson configuration. You just have to change the modifiers mask to `Modifier.PROTECTED | Modifier.STATIC`. (I never had (de)serializing static fields in mind and never use non-standard exclusion modifiers).

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thanks... This is what I want. Working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923430/very-different-result-when-testing-android-app-on-two-computers) answer. Basically, the serialVersionUID is added by InstantRun, disabling InstantRun solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to use `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` then use the `@Expose` annotation to explicitly mark what is or isn't (de)serialized.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int field1 = 2;
    @Expose private int field2 = 6;
    @Expose @SerializedName ("foo") private int field3 = 12;
}
```

gives you `{"field2":6, "foo":12}`. The field `field1` is excluded because it isn't annotated with `@Expose`.

Personally, I always use the `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` because it filters out any generated fields (like the *Instant Run* comment above). If you didn't annotate it with `@Expose`, it won't be serialized/deserialized.

Another way is to declare the field as `transient`.